# Can a field's transient property/flag be set through reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection, transient

Is there a simple way to specify if a field should be transient or not in Java with reflection, similar to how a field's accessibility flag can be set with setAccessible()?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection itself cannot alter code.

Java Agents should allow you to rewrite the class as it is loaded.

You can use reflection to alter `serialPersistentFields` if it exists (unlikely), before the serialisation mechanism caches the class data. You could use reflection in a highly version specific way to alter the data inside the serialisation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any direct way to do this in the Java API, but it is possible with something like JRebel or LiveRebel http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/comparison/.  You could use something like ASM from http://asm.ow2.org/ to rewrite the bytecode with transient modifiers on the relevant fields.  Then trigger JRebel/LiveRebel to replace the runtime version of the class.

I haven't tried automating this with ASM, but I have used JRebel with IntelliJ IDEA to perform changes like this successfully during interactive development.