# How can we add transient to existing class using reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any way to make field static or transient using java reflection API.

**EDIT:** I have some Beans that are already being serialised using soap api and is being used by some clients, for some clients i don't want to expose one or two fields.

Sure there are so many ways to do it without changing or adding transient keyword.

Just want to know if it can be done, and if so, how ?

**EDIT:** I wouldn't call it an API or framework issue, more like a design flaw...
I'm using apache axis2 for soap

Comment: Could you specify your need? It looks like a "solution before the problem" question.

Comment: Well, your comment looks more like a critic instead of helping

Comment: Sorry if you think about it this way... It is because most of the time, people ask for a way to implement a solution they imagine for their problem instead of stating the problem itself.

Comment: While it may seem useful to answer the question as is, it often isn't. If we send you down the wrong path and help you introduce a hack into your application that's going to actually make it even harder to maintain, we haven't helped one bit. :)

Answer (score 5):

No. Such a thing would require modifying the byte code of the class. A particular difficulty in the case of `static` fields is that they are accessed using different bytecodes than object fields.

I don't see a why a field couldn't be made `transient` in runtime, at least in theory, but the current reflection API doesn't allow it. See also: [Can a field's transient property/flag be set through reflection in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384441/can-a-fields-transient-property-flag-be-set-through-reflection-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the reflection api. I think there are some byte-code manipulation tools but in this case you can use the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern. It solves the problem but I think it is extremely ugly:

*(I omited the usual boilerplate from here such as interfaces)*

```
public class StaticDecorator {

    private static Object staticField;
    private Object yourObject;

    public StaticDecorator(Object yourObject) {
        this.yourObject = yourObject;
    }

    public static Object getStaticField() {
        return staticField;
    }

    public static void setStaticField(Object object) {
        staticField = object;
    }

}
```

I used `Object` for the type of the class you are going to wrap but of course you can substitute any type you want. Using an approach like this you can "decorate" any class with a static field.

If you are **really, extremely must** want a static field in an object at run time this can help you but I think that there is a design flaw lurking somewhere.

Comment: Can you clarify it further? What frameworks do you use? It seems more like a framework issue to me.

Comment: Edited again, let me know if you anything to comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your bean inside another bean that only exposes the fields that you'd like to expose through your API. For example, with an internal bean with the fields `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, where you do not want to expose `baz`.

[Lombok Delegation](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) can make this incredibly simple, but here's an example using plain-old-Java.

```
public class ExposedBean {
    private InternalBean internalBean;
    public ExposedBean(InternalBean internalBean) {
        this.internalBean = internalBean;
    }
    public String getFoo() { return internalBean.getFoo(); }
    public String getBar() { return internalBean.getBar(); }
}

public class InternalBean {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    private String baz;
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }
    public String getBar() { return bar; }
    public String getBaz() { return baz; }
}
```

**Original answer, regarding setting modifiers**

You can not set modifiers. You can check them, however.

```
Field myField = /* get a field object */;
if (Modifier.isTransient(myField.getModifiers()) {
    System.out.println("myField is transient.");
}

if (Modifier.isFinal(MyClass.class.getModifiers()) {
    System.out.println("MyClass is final.");
}
```

With more information about the problem you're trying to solve, we can suggest alternatives. `Member#getModifiers()` is not declared final, so you could possibly use a decorator. (The below code is 100% untested.)

```
public class FieldModifierDecorator extends Field {
    protected Field field;
    private int modifiers = -1;

    public static void decorate(Field field) {
        FieldModifierDecorator newInstance = new FieldModifierDecorator();
        newInstance.field = field;
        return newInstance;
    }

    public void overrideModifiers(int modifiers) {
        this.modifiers = modifiers;
    }

    public int getModifiers() {
        if (-1 == modifiers) {
            return field.getModifiers();
        }
        return modifiers;
    }
}

// Example usage
public Field makeFieldAppearTransient(Field field) {
    FieldModifierDecorator decoratedField = FieldModifierDecorator.decorate(field);
    decoratedField.overrideModifiers(field.getModifiers() | Modifier.TRANSIENT);

    // if (Modifier.isTransient(decoratedField.getModifiers())) {
    //     System.out.println("It looks transient, but really isn't.");
    //}

    return decoratedField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modfifying class information or byte code modification is definitely the wrong tool for the job. You are trying to solve a business problem with solely technical tools.

It sounds more like you need a permission concept. Users may have permission to see some fields. Based on that you could use java bean introspection to clear the values of those fields just before they are sent to the client.

However this might have its problems as well. A client should be able to determine if it has permission to see that field or not.